# have two files with different content but with the same name in the same folder

Tags: windows, directory

I'm wondering how I could have two of the same files with different code, but with the same name and extension in a folder on windows.

I'm working on reverse engineering something but it's obfuscated and I can work with that, I'm just unsure how to replace a specific file with the same name, it always replaces the wrong one (Because they have the same name)

In the folder, it only has 2 files with the same name, is there a way to bypass the already exists check in windows or to replace a file by size so it won't replace the wrong one?

Everything is in a jar file

Comment: You can't have two files with the same name and extension on Windows (or any other OS, AFAIK). Your choices are a) use a different name or extension; b) delete the original file and replace it with the new file; or c) use the original one as it is and discard the new one.